# Algorithmic advice: Identify points that are "near" a line out of a set of points

Tags: algorithm, quadtree

Given is a finite 2-dimensional continuous space, a set of points *s* from that space and a line `l: y = mx + b` through that space.
I want to filter out all points in *s* whose shortest distance from *l* is equal or smaller than a given constant *c*.

To achieve this I obviously could calculate each point's shortest distance from *l* and just filter by that result which would result in a time-complexity of *O(n)*. However I want the algorithm to be faster.

I have thought about using a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to partition the space.
[image: quadtree]

Each leaf in this tree has a reference of the point in *s* that is also contained in the corresponding partition.
Then I could test, which of the partitions corresponding to leafs of the quadtree are cut by the line (*Theta(log n)*) and just calculate the distance of points in those partitions and neighbored partitions.

Anyway I don't know if there are faster, more sophisticated algorithms or literature for this problem. Furthermore I am sure that there are some twists and errors in my current thought process. So I would appreciate some references and new ideas.

Comment: I would use the quadtree approach.

Comment: It looks like the common problem in computer graphics of how to pick objects in a 2D scene. Say all points are at the center of a circle with a radius of c. A ray sent along line l will hit all circles whose center is closer to the line than c.

Comment: @Shridhar R Kulkarni For just solving the problem for your points and line once, the complexity using a tree is still *O(n)* as you have to add all points to the tree. Are you planning to use the same set of points many times, with different lines? Only then, you can acheive sub-linear time I would say.

Comment: Hey Berthur! Was I tagged by mistake here?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni My bad, meant OP Hans Dampf . The mobile UI confused me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [kdtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) instead quadtree for better performance. The solution below works for both options.

You could use to tree traversal quadtree (from bigger quad to smallest quad). And you have three alternative options:

1. Current quad border (subrectangle) lies inside the line border, i.e. distance between the line and **farther** quad border is **less than or equal to constant** *c*. Then you should add all points from this quad (with addition tree traversal) to answer and ignore the quad inside.
2. Current quad border lies outside the line border, i.e. distance between the line and **nearest** quad border is **greater than constant** *c*. Then you should ignore the quad.
3. If is not 1) and is not 2) then you should divide quad (tree traversal) and go deeper.

I think what time complexity is *O(k log n)* where *k* is answer size when use kdtree.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I dont quite understand your idea of distance between the quad borders and the line. Since the line traverses the hole space it cuts the borders of quads. Wouldn't this just result in distance of zero? In fact every pair of lines that is not parallel would have a distance of zero. I see that quad borders have a startpoint and endpoint and are therefor not lines but this would lead to two different distances in generell.

Comment: @HansDampf
Quad is subrectangle of quadtree (as example is two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) as opposite corners). Distance between quad and the line is minimum distance between point (x, y) (where x1 <= x <= x2 and y1 <= y <= y2) and the line. It can be done without brute force of all points of course (split quad to four 2d segments and find minimum distance between some segment and the line).